# filter data from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter data in dataframe where one column is null. From source json file I am getting the value for the column as below:

```
col:null
```

The schema for the column is coming to as string.

When I am filtering the row I am still getting the record. None of the below commands are working. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
df.filter($"col" =!= "null")
df.filter($"col" =!= lit("null"))
```

Dataframe output is below

```
+----------+-------------------+
|RecordCnt |col                |
+----------+-------------------+
|    500000|               null|
+----------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare to null using equality operators. You need to use `is not null`, e.g.

```
val df2 = df.filter("col is not null")
```

or in the dataframe API,

```
val df2 = df.filter($"col".isNotNull)
```

Comment: i had tried that earlier and that did not work!

Comment: that too does not work. I tried with createOrReplaceTempView on the dataframe and added where col is not null which worked. Not sure why this is not working using filter clause!

Comment: Oh, did you assign the result to a new dataframe? like `val df2 = df.filter("col is not null")`

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you want to apply as where clause you can do it as .

val newDF = df.where(df("col").isNotNull)

OR

// if you want to filter as 
val newDF = df.filter($"col".isNotNull)

OR 

val newDF =df.filter("col is not null")
```